# Show that f(x,y) = a^2/x*y^a+1 is a density function

Tags: probability, functions

i need help with solving the corresponding integral. I never took multivariable calculus, so im pretty bad at integration anyway, but i have to start somewhere.

I have to show that the function $ f(x,y) = \frac{a^2}{x*y^{a+1}} $ is a density function.
Given the fact that $x,y \geq 1$, this thing is going to be positive anyway. But, as i mentioned above, i have trouble showing the integration part.
Ive managed to work out the integral, with $F(x,y) = -a*y^{-a}*ln(x)$, but i have trouble  showing that the corresponding integral equals 1.

Thy for the help

Comment: What is the domain?  Is it $x \geq 1$ and $y \geq 1$?

Comment: yes, and there is another condition: $x \leq y$

Comment: @TobyV. That should be mentioned in the OP, not the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be the domain in question:
$$
    D = \left\{(x,y)\mid 1 \leq x < \infty, x \leq y <\infty\right\}
$$
Then the integral is
$$
    I = \iint_D \frac{a^2}{xy^{a+1}}\,dA
      = \int_1^\infty \int_x^\infty \frac{a^2}{x y^{a+1}}\,dy \,dx
$$
It looks like you antidifferentiated the integrand with respect to each variable consecutively.  But to do an iterated integral, you need to do one at a time (evaluating in between).  Thus:
$$
    \begin{split}
        \int_1^\infty \int_x^\infty \frac{a^2}{x y^{a+1}}\,dy \,dx
        &= \int_1^\infty \left[-\frac{a}{x y^{a}}\right]^{y=\infty}_{y=x}\,dx \\
        &= \int_1^\infty \frac{a}{x^{a+1}}\,dx \\
        &= \left.-\frac{1}{x^{a}}\right|^{x=\infty}_{x=1}=1\\ 
    \end{split}
$$
You should really find a good book on multivariable integration and “review” it because you won't be able to bluff your way through problems like this.